# Updating Python tkinter label in realtime

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to update my label in python *after* the loop has started. 
Sadly I get the error

```
File "mygui.py", line 19, in <module>
GUI.user_said("General Kenobi")
File "mygui.py", line 16, in user_said
self.my_label['text'] = self.label_text
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1486, in __setitem__
self.configure({key: value})
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1479, in configure
return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1470, in _configure
self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!label"
```

which doesn't help me at all...
My Code:

```
from tkinter import *

class MyGUI:
"""A simple class"""

def __init__(self):
    self.__main_window = Tk()
    self.label_text = "Hello There"
    self.my_label = Label(self.__main_window, text=self.label_text)
    self.my_label.pack()
    self.__main_window.mainloop()

def user_said(self, users_request):
    """Returns what the user says"""
    self.label_text = "You said:\n{}\n\n".format(users_request)
    self.my_label.config(text=self.label_text)

GUI = MyGUI()
GUI.user_said("General Kenobi")
```

I'm very glad if someone helps me to find a solution for my problem.

Comment: First indent you code, XD.

Comment: @Mr.Zeus, pardon?

Comment: Indent the the function after your class. It needs to be indented to be part of your class.

Comment: The line `GUI = MyGUI()` does not complete execution until the window is closed (due to the call to `mainloop()` inside the class's `__init__()`).  Therefore, the following line is trying to set the text of a Label that no longer exists.  You either need to call `mainloop()` as the very last thing in the program, OR have some way to invoke `user_said()` during the execution of the mainloop (a button, perhaps).

Comment: Wow, I'm so stupid. I just asked too fast for an update... It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because `MyGUI.__init__` calls `self.__main_window.mainloop()`, it will not return until the main window is destroyed. Therefore, by the time you call `GUI.user_said("General Kenobi")`, none of the widgets exist any more.